# NotSupportedException when calling MakeGenericTypeDefinition with generated type

Tags: f#, type-providers

I'm trying to implement a simple generative type provider in F#. One thing that popped up is that apparently generating a quotation containing call of a generic method where generic type parameter is substituted with a generated type is not supported. A simple example to demonstrate this behaviour:

First, the definition of the a generic method and some utils:

```
module Printer =

    let print (name: string) (value: 'T) =
        printfn "%s: %O" name value

module Provided = 

    let property name propertyType value =
        ProvidedProperty(name, propertyType, GetterCode = (fun _ -> value))

    let ctor () = ProvidedConstructor([], InvokeCode = (fun _ -> <@@ () @@>))
```

Then, within the type provider, the following simple `another` type is defined:

```
let providerTempAssembly = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), ".dll") |> ProvidedAssembly
let provider = ProvidedTypeDefinition(asm, ns, "Provider", Some typeof<obj>, IsErased = false, HideObjectMethods = true)

// Create empty "AnotherType" type with parameterless constructor
let another = ProvidedTypeDefinition("AnotherType", Some typeof<obj>, IsErased = false)
another.AddMember <| Provided.ctor()
provider.AddMember another
```

And finally, `target` type with `PrintMembers()` method where `Printer.print` is attempted to be called:

```
let target = ProvidedTypeDefinition("TargetType", Some typeof<obj>, IsErased = false)

let properties = [
    Provided.property "Id" typeof<int> <| Expr.Value 10;
    Provided.property "Name" typeof<string> <| Expr.Value "abc";
    Provided.property "AnotherProp" another <| Expr.Value null
]

target.AddMembers properties

target.AddMember <| ProvidedMethod("PrintMembers", [], typeof<unit>, InvokeCode = (fun args ->
    let this = args.[0]

    // MethodInfo of Printer.print<'T> method definition where concrete type of 'T is not specified
    let printMethod = 
        match <@@ Printer.print "foo" 42 @@> with 
        | Call(_, x, _) -> x.GetGenericMethodDefinition()

    let printStatements = 
        properties
        |> List.map (fun prop ->
            try
                let genericPrint = printMethod.MakeGenericMethod(prop.PropertyType)
                Expr.Call(genericPrint, [Expr.Value(prop.Name); Expr.PropertyGet(this, prop)]) // fails here
            with
            | ex -> 
                printfn "Failed to generage call of Printer.print for property %s of type %O. Error details: %O" prop.Name prop.PropertyType ex
                reraise())

    // Generates sequence of expressions that call Printer.print for each property
    List.foldBack (fun t acc -> Expr.Sequential(t, acc)) printStatements <| Expr.Value(())))

target.AddMember <| Provided.ctor()

provider.AddMember target
providerTempAssembly.AddTypes [provider]
this.AddNamespace(ns, [provider])
```

*Full source code with required boilerplate can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/takemyoxygen/d6d3a961dca1a8f161abcc13e02fe590/5258a65d6700156e8e9423085eb29c45be138a7e)*

An attempt to use such type provider results in the following error:

```
Failed to generage call of Printer.print for property AnotherProp of type AnotherType. Error details: System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
at System.Reflection.Emit.MethodOnTypeBuilderInst.GetParametersInternal () <0x1a27320 + 0x00027> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Reflection.Emit.MethodOnTypeBuilderInst.GetParameters () <0x1a272f0 + 0x00020> in <filename unknown>:0 
at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.mkStaticMethodCall (System.Reflection.MethodInfo minfo, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1 args) <0x5301740 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr.Call (System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1 arguments) <0x53016e0 + 0x0004f> in <filename unknown>:0 
at <StartupCode$GenericMethodsTypeProvider>.$GenericMethodsTypeProvider+printStatements@62.Invoke (ProviderImplementation.ProvidedTypes.ProvidedProperty prop) <0x5300250 + 0x000ff> in <filename unknown>:0
```

So, `Printer.print<int>` and `Printer.print<string>` can be called, but not`Printer.print<AnotherType>`.

Is it a type providers limitation or there is some another way to generate a quotation where generic methods can be called with generated types?

**UPD**: Apparently, attempts to call non-generic methods of generic classes where one of the type arguments is bound to generated type also fail with `NotSupportedException`. Let's say I want to generate the following quotation:

```
<@@ 
     if this.Property.IsSome 
     then Printer.print "Property" this.Property.Value
     else Printer.print "Property" "Absolutely nothing"
@@>
```

for a property of type `AnotherType option` (`AnotherType` is generated above). The following code:

```
if property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && 
    property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<option<_>> 
then
    let isSomeProp = property.PropertyType.GetProperty("IsSome") // fails here
    let valueProp = property.PropertyType.GetProperty("Value")
    let underlyingType = property.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.[0]
    let genericPrint = printMethod.MakeGenericMethod(underlyingType)

    let propertyName = property.Name
    let isSome = Expr.PropertyGet(isSomeProp, [Expr.PropertyGet(this, property)])
    let getValue = Expr.PropertyGet(Expr.PropertyGet(this, property), valueProp)
    let printPropertyValue = Expr.Call(genericPrint, [Expr.Value(propertyName); getValue])

    Expr.IfThenElse(isSome, printPropertyValue,<@@ Printer.print propertyName "Absolutely nothing" @@>)
```

fails with:

```
Failed to generage call of Printer.print for property MaybeAnotherProp of type Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[AnotherType]. Error details: System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
at System.Reflection.MonoGenericClass.GetPropertyImpl (System.String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Type returnType, System.Type[] types, System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[] modifiers) <0x1a54ff0 + 0x00027> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Type.GetProperty (System.String name) <0x1968c30 + 0x00055> in <filename unknown>:0 
at <StartupCode$GenericMethodsTypeProvider>.$GenericMethodsTypeProvider+printStatements@64.Invoke (ProviderImplementation.ProvidedTypes.ProvidedProperty property) <0x5346898 + 0x000eb> in <filename unknown>:0
```

*Full code is [in updated gist](https://gist.github.com/takemyoxygen/d6d3a961dca1a8f161abcc13e02fe590/46c882b382a7f612bb2b5618f352ecf27b0bc98a)*

So, why these actions are not supported and are there any workarounds?

**UPD2:**
Indeed, @kvb's advice to use `ProvidedTypeBuilder.MakeGenericMethod` instead of `someMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod` solves the first case. In this case, it is indeed possible to call generic methods with generated types.

However, apparently it's not possible to call generic methods where one of the arguments is also of a generic type when type argument is bound to a generated type. In other words, it's possible to call method

```
let foo<'T> (x: 'T) = printfn "%A" x
```

but not

```
let foo<'T> (x: option<'T>) = printfn "%A" x
```

Apparently, this is a limitation of  a combination of reflection and type providers. I created [an issue](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.StarterPack/issues/91) that contains a bit more information.

The workaround is to pass arguments of generic types as instances of `obj` instead:

```
let foo<'T> (x: obj) = x :?> option<'T> |> printfn "%A"
```

Comment: Generating a generic type is not supported but you can generate a generative provided type with concrete implementations.

Comment: You might try using `ProvidedTypeBuilder.MakeGenericMethod(printMethod, ...)` instead of `printMethod.MakeGenericMethod(...)`.

Comment: @kvb, thanks, indeed, it solves the first part of my issue. I've also updated the question with some more info and discovered workaround.